# Unsupported Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Supported ones are: [text/xml] in Jdev

Tags: java, web-services, soapui

I'm trying to consume a mock service from SoapUI in Jdev by generating proxy client but i keep getting the following exception in Jdev :

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.UnsupportedMediaException: Unsupported Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 Supported ones are: [text/xml]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:284)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:118)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.decode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:278)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:180)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:83)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:105)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:587)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:546)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:531)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:428)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:211)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:124)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:98)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:107)
    at $Proxy33.searchOrder(Unknown Source)
    at beans.util.search.ShowOrderSearchResults.getOrderSearchResults(ShowOrderSearchResults.java:43)
    at beans.util.search.ShowOrderSearchResults.main(ShowOrderSearchResults.java:32)
```

Can anyone tell me what is the probable cause of this as I'm new to webservices.

Comment: It seems that one of two things: you are not sending a correct SOAP request (XML format), or your WS is expecting that `Content-Type` http header is set to `text/xml; charset=iso-8859-1`.

Answer (score 6):

This error is *not* about the request, but about the response. The JAX-WS *client-side* runtime has sent the request and is about to process the response, but the response is not text/xml as expected (a SOAP response). Two possible root causes:

1. You are using the wrong URL for the web service and the web server sends a HTML response, either with the content of the URL, or an error page - for example 404 Not found.
2. Something breaks inside the web service (for example an unhandled exception) and the web server sends a HTML response with the error information - for example 500 Internal server error.

Answer (score 0):

I have expanded on the possible causes, workarounds and solutions to handling these invalid responses in my answer on the following question:

[UnsupportedMediaException -> how do you get the actual response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52446318/unsupportedmediaexception-how-do-you-get-the-actual-response)

Summary of that answer:

- Set debug options to dump the HTTP request+response to investigate the error
- Optionally rewrite the `Content-type` of the reponse to better fit the content you're getting
- Use custom HTTP processing code to retrieve the HTTP body content in your application