# Unsupported Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8 Supported ones are: [application/soap+xml]

Tags: java

I'm trying to call a web service from my client (Java project on Eclipse), I've used wsimport to generate the classes (models) from the xsd and the service interface that acts as a proxy to the actual web service. The method from the service I'm calling accepts a requestElement and then is supposed to return a responseElement but I'm receiving this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.UnsupportedMediaException: Unsupported Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8 Supported ones are: [application/soap+xml]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:220)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.StreamSOAP12Codec.decode(StreamSOAP12Codec.java:88)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:151)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.decode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:299)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.createResponsePacket(HttpTransportPipe.java:268)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:217)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:130)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:124)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1121)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1035)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1004)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:862)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:448)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:178)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:93)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:77)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:147)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31.calculateQuoteApplyWeb(Unknown Source)
    at TestDestinyTax.main(TestDestinyTax.java:96)
```

Here's what the main driver code looks like:

```
public class TestTax {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SabrixLayerException_Exception, MalformedURLException {
        
        java.net.URL wsdlUrl = new URL(/*hidden wsdlUrl*/);
        TaxSabrixService_Service service = new TaxSabrixService_Service(wsdlUrl, new QName(/*hidden namespace and servicename*/));
        TaxSabrixService taxService = service.getPort(TaxSabrixService.class);
        BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider) taxService;     
        bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, wsdlUrl.toString());
        
        
        
        CalculateQuoteApplyWebElement req = new CalculateQuoteApplyWebElement();
        QuoteApplyWebRequest quoteReq = new QuoteApplyWebRequest();
        
        
        /*
         * calculateQuoteApplyWebElement
         *      QuoteApplyWebRequest
         *          UserCredentials
         *              -userName
         *              -password
         *          List<InvoiceApplyWeb> invoices
         *          (InvoiceApplyWeb)
         *              -List<LineApplyWeb> list
         *              -Address billToAddressShipToAddress
         *              -Address shipFromAddress
         *              
         * 
         */
        

        // credentials
        UserCredentials credentials = new UserCredentials();
        credentials.setUserName("userName");
        credentials.setPassword("password");
        
        // itemAmountPrefix
        ItemAmountPrefix itemAmount = new ItemAmountPrefix();
        itemAmount.setAmount(100.0);
        itemAmount.setInvoicePrefix("CR");
        itemAmount.setDiscount(0.0);
        itemAmount.setItemID("");
        
        // lineApplyWeb
        LineApplyWeb line = new LineApplyWeb();
        line.setItemAmount(itemAmount);
        
        // Address setup
        Address billToAddressShipToAddress = new Address();
        Address shipFromAddress = new Address();
        billToAddressShipToAddress.setPostalCode("85040");
        billToAddressShipToAddress.setCountry("US");
        billToAddressShipToAddress.setState("HI");
        billToAddressShipToAddress.setPostalCodePlus4("");
        billToAddressShipToAddress.setCity("Kona");
        
        shipFromAddress.setPostalCode("41423");
        shipFromAddress.setCountry("US");
        shipFromAddress.setState("NM");
        shipFromAddress.setPostalCodePlus4("");
        shipFromAddress.setCity("");
        
        // InvoiceApplyWeb setup
        InvoiceApplyWeb invoice = new InvoiceApplyWeb();
        invoice.getLines().add(line);
        invoice.setBillToAddressShipToAddress(billToAddressShipToAddress);
        invoice.setShipFromAddress(shipFromAddress);
        
        // QuoteApplyWeb setup
        quoteReq.setUserCredentials(credentials);
        quoteReq.getInvoices().add(invoice);
        
        // finish CalculateQuoteApplyWebElement setup
        req.setQuoteApplyWebRequest(quoteReq);
        
        //System.out.println( quoteWebElementToString(req) );
        try{
            System.out.println(taxService.calculateQuoteApplyWeb(req));
        } catch (@SuppressWarnings("restriction") com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.UnsupportedMediaException u) {
            System.out.println("CAUGHT EXCEPTION: "+u.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

How can I change that Content-Type to application/soap_xml for the response? I'm assuming that's where the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the SOAP server is sending a bad response.

- SOAP v1.1 uses content-type `text/xml`
- SOAP v1.2 uses content-type `application/soap+xml`

See:

- [Can a WSDL indicate the SOAP version (1.1 or 1.2) of the web service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736845/can-a-wsdl-indicate-the-soap-version-1-1-or-1-2-of-the-web-service)
- [Content Type text/xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250251/content-type-text-xml-charset-utf-8-was-not-supported-by-service)

As we can see in your stacktrace, the current code tries to process the response as SOAP v1.2: `StreamSOAP12Codec.decode(StreamSOAP12Codec.java:88)`.

But the server is sending the content type `text/xml`, which is not supported.
So either the server/WSDL is lying (it's actually SOAP 1.1) or the server is sending a bad response, in which case it's the responsibility of the server to fix it.

You can try to modify your local client/WSDL to version 1.1, regenerate your model, and see if that solves it.
You also mention 'acts as a proxy', is that just the generated code, or are you actually running a proxy between the client and the server? In that case you need to reconfigure the proxy.

Otherwise you'll have to either:

- Contact the server owner and report this problem
- Find a way to rewrite the content-type of the response on your client side

Some references on that last point:

- [SOAP unsupported media exception text/plain Supported ones are: [text/xml]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64866031/soap-unsupported-media-exception-text-plain-supported-ones-are-text-xml)
- [Unsupported Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Supported ones are: [text/xml] in Jdev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25406563/unsupported-content-type-text-html-charset-utf-8-supported-ones-are-text-xml)

Comment: Thanks so much for this information, makes much more sense! As for the references on rewriting the content-type of the response in the client code, I’m not seeing a lot of information on how to go about that specifically. How would I be able to change the content-type of that response (that’s coming in as type generated response element object)? I’ve tried to look into more information on that but I’ve been unsuccessful.

Comment: @jkimbuen i'm afraid there is no easy way to solve this, all solutions i've seen are fairly involved. The first link suggests installing a proxy server in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65065756/18699445) answer. Via the second link you can end up at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71734557/18699445), which i've just updated with a demonstration on my github.

Comment: Or you could try Apache CXF, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50841933/how-can-i-make-jaxws-parse-response-without-checking-content-type-header) question. It's still on my todo list to test this option.